# jQuery and JSON to retrieve data from database in Java web app?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jakarta-ee, web

I am doing a Java web application project wherein it one of its purposes is to display all data from the database. It uses the Hibernate, Struts2 and Spring frameworks. However, I want the application to retrieve the data using jQuery and JSON. Would that even be possible?

How would I do that? And are there any tools needed to achieve that? I can't find any tutorials online. Hope someone could help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java script can be used in any HTML widgets. It is not necessary that should be spring , struts ,etc. ultimately all these frame works will spit the HTML outputs. So what you have to learn is how can you invoke a java script function in the HTML widget. For your refrence I would to give some example

```
<spring:bind path="accountForm.account.someData">
<SELECT name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" size="1" onChange=dynDisplay();>
</spring>
```

So Here I am calling a method called dynDisplay() on selecting of the widget someData.like this you can call any function and perform any task using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and actually the best scope, i recommend you to read the following tutorials and examples and then come up with a solution:

To convert java objects to json and viceversa use Jackson

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

A great tutorial on Spring MVC and Hibernate integration:

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html

To get a json response out of a web service with jquery

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Finally a simple Struts 2 and Spring integration example

http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-integration-example/